# How to get value from search suggestions after keying in text using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

When you enter something for example apple into the search bar at https://finance.yahoo.com/ there is a search suggestions menu that appears.[image: yahoo finance]

I am trying to get it to return a list, dictionary or dataframe of the values in that drop down box.

For example {'AAPL':'Apple Inc.', 'APLE':'Apple Hospitality REIT,Inc.',.....}

Here is my code,

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe',options=options)

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(0.5)

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yfin-usr-qry"]')
inputElement.send_keys('apple')
time.sleep(0.5)

web_elem_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fin-srch-assist"]/div[1]/div/ul[1]')
suggests = [web_elem.text for web_elem in web_elem_list]

print(suggests)

driver.close()
```

but it keeps saying TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable. I'm sure I've selected the list. How do I get it to work the way I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `xpath` for the list:

```
.//ul[@class='M(0)']/li/div/div/div

web_elem_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//ul[@class='M(0)']/li/div/div/div')
```

This is not the correct xpath:

```
//*[@id="fin-srch-assist"]/div[1]/div/ul[1]
```

Comment: i still get the same error ```TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable```

Comment: yeah sure, but do you mind telling me how you get the right xpath?

Comment: The more you practice better you get. Go through online documents or youtube videos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206882/discussion-between-pratik-and-anarchy).

Answer (score 0):

script something to populate the prefilled suggestions, then:

```
stocks = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.Ell.C(black).D(i).Va(tb)")
for x in stocks:
    print(x.text)
```